# How can I make the panel display a battery estimate for both batteries?

Tags: wingpanel, hardware, battery

Is there a way to detect whether the internal battery or the external battery is being used first? How do I force elementary OS to use external battery first? I don't want the internal battery to be depleted first since it is not swap-able.

The problem persists after you restart the computer. The OS no longer combines the battery life of both batteries, but rather looks at only the battery life of one of the batteries. Is there a way to fix this permanently so it shows the battery life of both batteries?

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION:** Actually, I just discovered that the external battery is being used first. It was a simple removal of external battery and checking what battery power is at and the putting in the external battery and check what battery power is at again. Then I deduced which battery elementary OS is using first.

I originally thought the internal battery was being used first because the battery life was extremely low, around 2 hours when I normally should have around 8 hours. Then I discovered elementary OS was not recognizing my external battery. I fixed it by removing the external battery and re-inserting it while the computer is on. Then it recognized my external battery and the battery percentage and timer on the wing-panel now displays the correct combined percentage and time left of **both** batteries. But you need to do this every time you turn on the computer, and I am wondering if there is a permanent solution.

Comment: OP, can you please use the "Answer" text field below to post your solution so that this question can be closed?

Comment: Actually the solution was temporary, I need to keep removing the battery and putting it in if I want the battery life estimate to be for both batteries. That's why I edited it. Maybe I should say the solution was temporary.

Comment: though it is temporary, but that is a "solution", please add to _answer_ :)

Comment: Hardware Infos? And please add the last few lines of `dmesg` after the battery has been recognized.

Answer (score 2):

TEMPORARY SOLUTION: Actually, I just discovered that the external battery is being used first. It was a simple removal of external battery and checking what battery power is at and the putting in the external battery and check what battery power is at again. Then I deduced which battery elementary OS is using first.

I originally thought the internal battery was being used first because the battery life was extremely low, around 2 hours when I normally should have around 8 hours. Then I discovered elementary OS was not recognizing my external battery. I fixed it by removing the external battery and re-inserting it while the computer is on. Then it recognized my external battery and the battery percentage and timer on the wing-panel now displays the correct combined percentage and time left of both batteries. But you need to do this every time you turn on the computer, and I am wondering if there is a permanent solution.